# Can't Add Foreign Key MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I am using PHP MySQL and am trying to add a foreign key to a table called agents with a column called AreaID that should be the Foreign Key to the area Tables AreaID PK.
 I used this query and although it works while adding foreign keys linking to other tables, it wont work to link to the area table.

```
ALTER TABLE properties
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AreaID)
REFERENCES area(AreaID)
```

The error I revive is:

```
ALTER TABLE properties ADD FOREIGN KEY ( AreaID ) REFERENCES AREA( AreaID )
```

MySQL said:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'area(AreaID)' at line 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are these column have the same data type? `properties.AreaID` and `AREA.AreaID`?

Answer (score 5):

**AreaId** column must have same **datatype**, **length** and **signed/unsigned** attribute in both table. For example in **Area** table **AreaId** column is **INT(10) UNSIGNED** then properties table must have column with same **INT(10) UNSIGNED** column. You can **change the column name** but **datatype**, **length** and **signed** attribute **must** be the same.

Try this **ALTER** Statement and Check this link [**MySQL Foreign Key Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
ALTER TABLE properties 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Area 
    FOREIGN KEY (AreaID) 
    REFERENCES AREA(AreaID) 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all characteristics of two fields are the same.

Comment: Yes Both AreaIDs are of data type int

Comment: I removed the area table and made it again with only an ID field and a name field and the problem persisted. I then removed it and changed the name to town and the id to TownID and it works. I don't know if area is some SQL term that is messing it up but no matter what I done t would not work when the table was called area

Comment: @user1947428 Not just type, but characteristics. That means that an INT(9) can't be a FK to a field of INT(12), and you can't point an UNSIGNED field at a SIGNED one. Could you paste the CREATE TABLE statements into your post?

Answer (score 0):

check the database.. **InnoDB** only supports Foreign Keys constraints

Comment: i think so. myisam does not support foreign key constraints.. use innodb. it only support foregin key.